# How to use php foreach loop in MailGun API

Tags: php, api, mailgun

I installed mailgun on a google VM Instance, shortly to know that I can not send billing emails to my clients on outgoing ports (25,587,etc...) so I signed up to MailGun, I created and bought the basic plan...

Everything is working fine, if I send posted values ex. $_POST['email'] and $_POST['subject'], but for a billing email I want to fetch data from the DB and inject it in the MailGun parameters, note that I am using PHP and my code looks like that

```
$mg->messages()->send('xxxx.co.uk', [
      'from'    => 'xxxx@xxxx.co.uk', 
      'to'      => ''.$_SESSION['user_email'].'',
      'bcc'    => 'xxxxx@xxxxxx.xxx', 
      'subject' => 'Your Treatment Order with xxxxxx', 
      'html'    => '
                    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//IETF//DTD HTML//EN"">
                    <html>
                    <head>
                    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
                    <title>Your Treatment Order with XXX</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                    <table width="550" height="200" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="border:1px solid #777777;  padding: 25px; margin-top: 25px;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                    <tr><td align="center" colspan="5" style="background-color:#303f46; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;"><img src="http://www.xxxxx.co.uk/images/logo.png"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td height="1" bgcolor="#777777" colspan="5"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td height="10" colspan="5"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td height="1" bgcolor="#777777" colspan="5"></td></tr><tr><td height="5" colspan="5"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td align="left" class="hometitle" colspan="5">Your Treatment Order with XXXX</td></tr><tr><td height="5" colspan="5"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td height="1" bgcolor="#777777" colspan="5"></td></tr><tr><td height="5" colspan="5"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td align="left" class="hometext" colspan="5"><span style="color: #777777";>
                        <p>Hello,</p>
                        <p>Thanks for your order. We’ll let you know once your item(s) have <b>confirmed</b>. Your estimated confirmation time will not exceed few hours. You can view the details of your order by visiting <a href="http://www.xxxx.co.uk/orders.php?id='.$transactionId.'">My Orders</a> section on xxxx.co.uk.</p>
                        <p><b>ORDER DETAILS</b></p>
                        <p>Order Number: '.$transactionId.'</p>
                        <p>Placed on '.date('l dS F Y', strtotime($paymentDate)).'</p>
                        <p>Order Total:  £ '.$originalAmount.'.00</p>
                        <p>Coupon Used: '.$couponCode.'</p>
                        <p>Total After Discount: £ '.$amount.'.00</p>
                    </td></tr>'.foreach($orders as $order_real){ $order_real['transaction_id'] }.'<tr><td height="10" colspan="5"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td height="1" bgcolor="#777777" colspan="5"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td height="10" colspan="5"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="5"><p>Sending luck, good health and best regards as always<br>XXXX team</p></td></tr>
                    <tr><td height="10" colspan="5"></td></tr>
                    </table>
                    </body>
                    '
]);
```

the code works fine if I remove the foreach($orders as $order_real){ ... } but returns HTTP ERROR 500 when I include it like below, maybe its the concatenation? how to do it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `foreach()` doesn't return anything, you can't use it in a string concatenation like that.

Comment: I know its just a demo code, I am willing to put some fetched data in a <tr><td> structure... how to use it? how to concatenate?

Comment: Build the HTML outside of the function parameters where you can control it better - and build a variable separately with the foreach  and include it as another ordinary variable.  Doing too much in a segment/line of code makes like more complicated than is needed.

Comment: thank you its almost working now, the funny thing is that I builded a lot of similar stuff two years ago and now I can not remember anything... maybe because I am working 16 hours a day, 6 days a week lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foreach()` isn't a function -- it doesn't return anything, so you can't use it in a string concatenation like that. You can to use the `.=` operator to continually append HTML to a variable for each iteration of your loop:

```
$html = '... lots of HTML ... ';
foreach (...) {
    $html .= '... more HTML ...';
}
$html .= '... some more HTML ...';
```